# Autoconf: how to disable language checking completely (no C compiler available)

Tags: autoconf

I am using [Autoconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoconf) to provide a configuration for our [Common Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp)-based application. The "compilation" process (loading and dumping of Common Lisp images) does not need any C or whatever compiler, only a (supported) Common Lisp interpreter is necessary.

This works all out nicely, but recently I tried to install it on a [Mac OS X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X) system without C compiler installed, and it failed, because the Autoconf-generated [*configure* script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configure_script) tries to check for a C compiler, etc.

I know of `AC_LANG`, but none of the languages supported are usable.

Is there a way to do the equivalent of `AC_LANG([none])` or similar, disabling all checks for all kind of compilers whatsoever?